# Dealing with non-inherited methods in a subclass

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a class Voucher:

```
public abstract class Voucher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; protected set; }
        public const string SuccessMessage = "Applied";
    }
```

and a subclass GiftVoucher

```
public class GiftVoucher : Voucher
    {
    }
```

and another subclass DiscountVoucher

```
public class DiscountVoucher : Voucher
    {
        public decimal Threshold { get; private set; }
        public string FailureMessage { get { return "Please spend £{0} to use this discount"; } }
    }
```

You can see that DiscountVoucher has a couple of specific properties Threshold and FailureMessage that respectively represent the amount of money you need to spend to get the discount and the failure message to display if the user has not spent that money.

My question is this.  I have a collection of Voucher objects and what I don't want to do in my code is something like this

```
if (voucher is DiscountVoucher)
{
   // cast voucher to a DiscountVoucher and then call the specific methods on it
}
```

because this is not at all maintainable.  At the same time I did not want to put those specific methods in the Voucher abstract class because they are not applicable to all types of Vouchers.  Does anyone know how to design this functionality?

Comment: What tasks do you have to perform on your collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what you've got here is a version of the strategy pattern. I don't think there's any getting away from eventually having to decide if you have one type of voucher or another but you can limit the number of variations - voucher categories if you will - using interfaces.

For instance you might end up with five vouchers which implement interfaces called 'StandardVoucher' and three called 'DiscountVoucher' but instead of having to handle eight cases you now just have two.

The interfaces can cover a range of vouchers showing the available methods without worrying about the details of each vouchers implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case: No!

Handling specialized scenarios in a general code flow without any code handling the special cases does not work.

However in some cases you can cheat a little bit. You can implement virtual methods in the abstract base class that provides a default "nothing" implementation.

Could be a method that returns null, 0 or just does nothing.

In this case

```
public virtual string FailureMessage { get { return string.Empty; } }
```

might be a reasonable implementation.

I guess that your implementation looks a lot like the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Then it is perfectly normal to have void implementations for steps not applicable to certain implementations.

Comment: Problem is though, this breaks basic OO principles.  We shouldn't have things in Voucher that are not applicable to all Vouchers.

Comment: It does not break OO principles. It would perfectly make sense to return an empty failure message from Voucher, meaning that no error ocurred.

Comment: If your principles does not work in practice: use other principles. You need to decide what a generic voucher should be able to handle and put them in the base class. That does not necessarily correspond to the actions that applies to the physical object that you model your base class after.

Comment: A problem with the approach shown in the question is, that someone working with vouchers needs to know that voucher A can produce an error, but voucher B not. In a good OO-design as little as possible should be known about an object. Whenever possible things should remain hidden in the object and the object should be treated like a black box.

Comment: From a consumer perspective all vouchers can produce errors. You don't need to know that B will never produce any error in the current implementation. If you run into situations where B needs to be handled differently you either need to redefine the interface of B or create a separate B-handling strategy.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot, because iterating over more general objects and then calling specific methods would require using polymorphism to have dedicated functionality in each subclass. Without a method in the superclass to override, you have no way to obtain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right to be suspicious of the code you describe.

My first thought is that if members of `DiscountVoucher` aren't broad enough to exist as virtual or abstract in `Voucher`, then a function that takes a `Voucher` as a parameter should not touch them.

So, to solve the problem, I'd say you could do one of two things:

First, you could add virtual methods or properties to `Voucher`, e.g.

```
public abstract class Voucher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; protected set; }
    public const string SuccessMessage = "Applied";
    public decimal Threshold { get { return 0.0; } }
    public string FailureMessage { get { return ""; } }
}
```

Second, you can add methods that do what you expect for each `Voucher`. You've grouped them together as vouchers, so think about what they have in common. If, say, `GiftVoucher` and `DiscountVoucher` are both doing their own calculations to determine if they apply to the current `ShoppingCart`, then you could have a `Voucher` method called `isValid()` to detect this. For example,

```
public abstract class Voucher
{
    public bool isValid(ShoppingCart sc);
    public string FailureMessage { get { return "This voucher does not apply"; } }
    // ...
}

public class DiscountVoucher : Voucher
{
    private decimal Threshold;
    public override bool isValid(ShoppingCart sc)
    {
        return (sc.total >= Threshold);
    }
    public override string FailureMessage
    {
        get { return FormatString("Please spend £{0} to use this discount", Threshold); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are just cases where you will have to cast. Here I would implement a general error checking mechanism:

```
public abstract class Voucher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string SuccessMessage { get { return "Applied"; } }
    public virtual string FailureMessage { get { return String.Empty; } }
    public virtual bool Ok { get { return true; } }
}

public class GiftVoucher : Voucher { }

public class DiscountVoucher : Voucher
{
    public decimal Threshold { get; private set; }
    public override string FailureMessage { get { return "Please spend £{0} to use this discount"; } }
    public override bool Ok { get { return Value >= Threshold; } }
}
```

You can then test the integrity of a voucher of any type without casting:

```
if (voucher.Ok) {
    Console.WriteLine(voucher.SuccessMessage);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine(voucher.FailureMessage);
}
```

As a general rule, try to let objects do their own stuff (here to test if they are OK) instead of doing it from the "outside". Even the fact, that no error can occur in a GiftVoucher needs not to be known by the "outer world".

Comment: Just want to say though that the implementation of Ok is wrong.  The value refers to the value of the voucher (£5 off) and Threshold refers to how much you need to spend before you get the £5 off (eg you need to spend £50).  So, here is the problem.  You quite rightly say that objects should do the calculations themselves but this would mean that I need to give Voucher another property (the amount that the user has spent).  Then, in the Ok method I can compare Threshold against that, would you agree with this approach?  The reason I ask is it seems a little unnatural for a Voucher to ...

Comment: ... know how much a user has spent.  But the alternative is that we decide from the "outside" whether a Voucher application was ok.  How do we deal with this contradiction?

Comment: @Sachin: The more natural solution would be to pass the amount spent as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Yes, replace the Ok property with a method having the amount or the discount passed.